# Wordpress Product Page displayed differently between Chrome/IE and Firefox

Tags: php, html, wordpress, e-commerce, alignment

When I added size variations to some of the products in my test store, the Product Options container automatically moved below the product image. I fixed the problem in Firefox, moving it to where I want on the right of the image using style="float..etc." as required, but the Product Options container refuses to move in other browsers. I've added screenshots to better explain what I mean.

Firefox [correct]:
[image: Product Options container where I want it to be.]

Chrome/IE [incorrect]:
[image: Product Options incorrectly beloew image.]

[Link to Code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:332f)

I've checked the DOCTYPE, I've used every possible combination of the display, position, float and margin functions I can think of but as yet no joy. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit css as follows:

form.product_form { width:390px; }
.product_description { clear: both; }

Comment: YES! That has taken about two months to figure out how to do it. Thank you! The only adjustment I had to make to your code is reduce the width of the addtocart line so it's properly scaled. 

Just a quick question, I've included that line after every instance of "form.product_form" appearing in the CSS, which is 17 times. Was that right?

Comment: You need to paste those codes only at the bottom of your css file, 1 time only.. No need to paste it on every instance/line